# Will it be safe to feed a 74VDC to a 56VDC Audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, transformer

I have a 400watt rms mono amp and the maximum VDC required by the amp is 56VDC at 7amps, so how much transformer's VAC do I need? If I use a transformer with 56VDC then there will be a voltage drop on load, so the amp will not get enough power and it will not make full power. I have a transformer 53VAC, but after rectifying it, I am getting 74VDC, will it be safe to feed the 74VC no load          to the amp.

Thank you. Regards.

Comment: Please add a link to a datasheet for the amp.  And preferably the transformer(s) too.

Comment: How much does the transformer weigh? By the way, if you can find a 120 VAC, 1500 W electric heater (easy) or a 5000 W, 220 VAC oven element (less easy), you might be able to use either of them as a direct load for your 53 VAC transformer. Measure the RMS voltage across it, under load, and measure the RMS current, as well. That should give you an idea if it can handle it. Another way is to weigh the thing. If 60Hz, it should weigh in at around 20 or more pounds.

Comment: Voltage will vary greatly depending on the music being played, determining voltage from full load isn't really a safe bet.

Comment: I doubt it. But without more info on the amp, it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: Thank you so very much, BTW is a local made, here is the link.


https://s23.postimg.org/l8onxw1wb/image.jpg

https://s17.postimg.org/czg1ynam7/image.jpg


BTW the transformer is a 45-0-45 VAC but when i test with multimeter it shows 53VAC.

Answer (score 1):

Audio amplifiers are generally fairly tolerant of supply voltage variations, but adding 20V would be a rather large jump. You'll need to go through the entire design and make sure that all of the components can tolerate the higher voltage. For example, the output transistors might only be rated for 60V.

Comment: Thank you so very much. The amp has 8 MOSFETS side by side, 4 IRFP9240 and 4 IRFP240 and 6 transistors.

Comment: Like I said, **you** will have to go through the entire design and make sure **all** the components can tolerate the higher voltage. Keep in mind that if you're really talking about bipolar supplies of +/-74V, then some components will have up to 150V across them, and need to be rated appropriately.

Comment: OK, i will try to get the info on the amp's design. Thanks much.